# React - nextjs Calling custom hook in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, authorization, use-effect

I'm trying to call 'useUser' custom hook, which uses useEffect & useSWR; inside useEffect of _app.tsx. But it throws,

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const params = {
          p1: "someText"
          m1: "someText02",
        };
    
        const { mutateUser } = useUser({
          redirectTo: "/test",
          redirectIfFound: true,
        });
    
        try {
          const fetchUser = async () => {
            mutateUser(
              await fetchJson("/api/login", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(params),
              })
            );
          };
          window && fetchUser();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("An unexpected error happened:", error);
        }
      }, []);
}
```

I'm not too sure why it's not working :(
I first separated this code in to another function, first I thought that's why it didn't work. Soon I realized that, it wasn't the cause.

Really appreciate if anyone could help!

Comment: Is the error message not clear enough on what the issue is? You can only call React hooks from the body of functional components or other hooks. ***NOTE*** that the `useEffect` callback function ***is not*** a React hook, and breaks the other rules of hooks regarding not being called in loops, conditions, and nested functions. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in the error message. You can't use `useUser` inside `useEffect`. You have to move it inside the body of the functional component.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const { mutateUser } = useUser({
     redirectTo: "/test",
     redirectIfFound: true,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const params = {
          p1: "someText"
          m1: "someText02",
        };
    
        try {
          const fetchUser = async () => {
            mutateUser(
              await fetchJson("/api/login", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(params),
              })
            );
          };
          window && fetchUser();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("An unexpected error happened:", error);
        }
      }, []);
}
```